# mysql group_concat inside while

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have this passenger table date:

[image]

Which means that in Reservation `000004`, there are two itineraries which are Itinerary `0000010 (AAC Hangar - Anvaya Cove)` and `0000011 (Anvaya Cove - AAC Hangar)`, and in every itinerary, there are two passengers (`0000007 (taiga)` and `0000011 riyuuji` are passengers of `0000010 AAC Hangar - Anvaya Cove while`0000008 minori`and`0000012 ami`are passengers of`0000011 Anvaya Cove - AAC Hangar).

I'm trying to concat them using `group_concat` but I can do only like this:

```
    $a=mysql_query("select group_concat(pass_name separator ', ') as 'pass' from passengers where reservno = '0000004' order by id asc") or die(mysql_error());
    $b=mysql_fetch_array($a);
    $c=$b['pass'];
```

with result: `taiga, minori, riyuuji, ami`.

**But I want it to look like this:** `taiga, riyuuji / minori, ami`

Is this possible using `group_concat`? I know this will involve `while` statements but as of now I still can't get the desired output. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause

```
select group_concat(pass_name separator ', ') as 'pass' 
from passengers 
where reservno = '0000004' 
GROUP BY reservno, id
order by id asc
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  group_concat(`pass` separator ' / ') `pass` 
FROM    ( 
            select group_concat(pass_name separator ', ') as 'pass' 
            from passengers 
            where reservno = '0000004' 
            GROUP BY reservno, id order by id asc 
        ) s
```

Comment: It only outputs `taiga, riyuuji`.

Comment: no it should output two, in your php script, you didn't loop `$a` that's is why it only gives you one record.

Comment: I looped it, and now it only outputs `minori, ami`.

Comment: see how [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) was used in the example, by th way, try running the query directly in phpmyadmin and see the result.

Comment: Oh yeah it does output fine in phpMyAdmin. I'm only passing `$c` into some PHP codes. How can I get this result to be concatted as well with separator `/`?

Comment: I have to pass the result in a PHP variable.

Comment: ok, try this, `SELECT group_concat(pass_name separator ' / ') \`pass\`
FROM
 (
  select  group_concat(pass_name separator ', ') as 'pass' 
  from  passengers 
  where  reservno = '0000004' 
  GROUP  BY reservno, id
  order  by id asc
 ) s`

Comment: oh it should be `pass`, here: `SELECT group_concat(\`pass\` separator ' / ') \`pass\` FROM ( select group_concat(pass_name separator ', ') as 'pass' from passengers where reservno = '0000004' GROUP BY reservno, id order by id asc ) s`

Comment: Wow! Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot again for helping! :D